# asp.net configuration login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, configuration

Hoping somebody can help me.
I'm running a VB project with asp.net configuration for the login. When I run Login.aspx from the account folder and try to log in it wont let me and says

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: `/VbProj new - Copy/default.aspx`

I don't have a default.aspx file anymore I deleted it the moment I created the site. The main page that it goes to should be index.aspx.

When I run the page index.aspx though from visual studio directly though and press logout it will let me log in again with no problems,
Could anyone tell me where im going wrong

Thanks

When i open the login page in account the url is

```
/VbProj%20new%20-%20Copy/Account/Login.aspx
```

yet the one from when i log out after running the index page is

```
/VbProj%20new%20-%20Copy/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fVbProj+new+-+Copy%2findex.aspx
```